# Is isCopy field always necessary in android?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

My usual JNI code that handles string from java is like that:

```
jboolean isCopy_something;

const char* something=env->GetStringUTFChars(somethingFromJava,&isCopy_something);

if(isCopy_something==JNI_TRUE){
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(somethingFromJava,something);
}
```

I think if I need one extra jboolean for each string from Java, it affects the readability of the code seriously, besides jboolean, I also need a if else statement to wrap the ReleaseStringUTFChars.

I remembered I saw some codes that only pass NULL instead of address of isCopy.

Can I call ReleaseStringUTFChars without checking isCopy in android?

I searched some post about isCopy field, but still not really understand the function of isCopy field in ReleaseStringUTFChars: when will isCopy become JNI_TRUE and when will become JNI_FALSE? Is it depend on platform? or depend on run time condition? or other condition?

Comment: _"when will become JNI_FALSE?"_ AFAIK, never, if we're talking specifically about Android. See e.g. the implementations of `GetStringUTFChars` in [Android 2.3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/gingerbread/vm/Jni.c) and [Android 4.4.4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/android-4.4.4_r1/vm/Jni.cpp) (Dalvik), and [Android 5.0.0](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art.git/+/android-5.0.0_r7/runtime/jni_internal.cc) (ART). That's not to say that it isn't good practice to check this at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

It is never necessary.

> Most often you pass NULL as the isCopy parameter.

—*The Java Native Interface. Programmer's Guide and Specification.* 1999. Sheng Liang.

> You can determine whether or not the data was copied by passing in a non-NULL pointer for the isCopy argument. This is rarely useful.

— [Andriod Developer JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html)

And, you *always* have to call ReleaseStringUTFChars for every successful call to GetStringUTFChars.

Answer (score 3):

As @tom-blodget has said, you should *always* call `ReleaseStringUTFChars` after `GetStringUTFChars`, if the result is not `NULL`.

`isCopy` just allows you to apply an optimization:

- If `isCopy` is `true`, you can safely modify the returned buffer without worrying the `String` on Java side is affected.
- If `isCopy` is `false`, you have to allocate another buffer and make a copy if you need to make amendments. Please do NOT modify the returned buffer directly! It is because in Java, the `String` type is immutable. All Java code expects that a `String` object never changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways VM can handle GetStringUTFChars method. in one way, VM will allocate memory for the native string(equivalent of java string) and in another way VM will just give a direct pointer which will point the java string. Former case isCopy will be TRUE and later case it is FALSE.

This behaviour is unknown to the user and solely decided by the VM at run time. Hence it is always recommended to check isCopy value before you release the native string. If isCopy is FALSE and if you release the native string which actually modifies the java string which is actually breaking the immutability rule of java.lang.String class.